# Calling delegate with multiple functions having return values

Tags: c#, delegates

I am trying to understand concept of delegates and have got a query. Suppose that we have a delegate defined with return type as int and accepting in 2 parameters of type int.

Delegate declaration:

```
 public delegate int BinaryOp(int x, int y);
```

Now, lets say we have 2 methods (add and multiply) both accepting 2 int parameters and returning an int result.

Code:

```
    static int Add(int x, int y)  
   {     
        return x + y; 
    }  

    static int Multiply(int x, int y)  
   {     
        return x * y; 
    }
```

Now, when add and multiply methods are added into this delegate, and then when the delegate is called like:

```
BinaryOp b = new BinaryOp(Add);
b+=new BinaryOp(Multiply);

int value=delegate_name(2,3);
```

Then, as per my understanding, both the methods are called. Now, result from which of the 2 methods is stored in the value variable? Or does it return an array in such case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, with a little bit of trickery and casting, you can get all of the results like this:

```
var b = new BinaryOp(Add);
b += new BinaryOp(Multiply);

var results = b.GetInvocationList().Select(x => (int)x.DynamicInvoke(2, 3));
foreach (var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

With output:

```
5
6
```

Answer (score 7):

You will get the return value of the last method added to the multicast delegate. In this case, you will get the return value of `Multiply`.

See the documentation for more on this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, invoking a multicast delegate calls all subscribed methods, but no, an array of results is not returned  - only the [result returned by the last subscriber](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6411514/314291) is returned.

To obtain the returned results of all subscribers, what you could do instead is to build a collection of typed `Func`s which you can then invoke and collate the results:

```
 IEnumerable<int> InvokeResults(IEnumerable<Func<int, int, int>> operations, 
                                int x, int y)
 {
     return operations.Select(op => op(x, y));
 }
```

And invoke like such:

```
 var results = InvokeResults(new Func<int, int, int>[] {Add, Multiply}, 2, 3);
```